# I am trying to execute the below if else condition, but else part is not executing 'if' condition is not satisfied

Tags: java, selenium

In the below piece of code, if login is successful, it should print 'Login passed' in the console. If it fails, it should print user who entered wrong credentials.

It is working fine if the login is failed. But when login is succesful[image], else part is not executed. Please help me out where i am doing wrong.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btnLogin\"]")).click();

  if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).getText().equals("Invalid Credential")) {

  System.out.println(user);  

  }

  else {

      System.out.println("Login Passed"); 
  }
```

**Error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/form/div/div/span"}
```

Comment: an Exception is thrown when the VM tries to handle your condition. You'll need to correct your code, or add Exception/Error handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way you can execute if-else ladder.

1. you can use try catch block and integrate the code with `isDisplayed()` method which is present in **Selenium**.

Something like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="btnLogin"]")).click();  

try{

if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).isDisplayed())
{
  System.out.println("Invalid");  
}

else{
System.out.println("Valid");  
}

catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("in exception");  
}
```

2. Use **list**(store invalid credentials xpath here) and check the size of it. If the size is 1, then there is surely error message from web page, otherwise the flow will go to else statement.

**Code**:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="btnLogin"]")).click();  
         if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).size()==1){
          System.out.println("Invalid");       
            }
         else {
          System.out.println("Login Passed"); 
        }
```

Comment: @Bhuvana : No problem mate.. happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium throws NoSuchElement exception when it fails to locate the element corresponding to the path you gave.

Use a try catch and handle that case.